# How to use LINQ to perform a simultaneous search of all child items

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My XML File is structured as follows:

```
<File>
<Setting1></Setting1>
<Setting2></Setting2>
<Options>
    <Option>
        <NameStartsWith>Br</NameStartsWith>
        <Data>1234</Data>
    </Option>
    <Option>
        <NameStartsWith>Ch</NameStartsWith>
        <Data>4567</Data>
</Option>
</Options>
</File>
```

What I would like to do is use LINQ for something like the below..

```
String Name = "Brian";
if(Name.StartsWith(LINQ.Any.NameStartsWith)))
{
 Console.WriteLine("The Answer is: " 1234);
}
```

At present I perform the above by looping through the `<Option>` fields with `foreach (XElement xe in Tests)`. But the real XML file is a lot more detailed than this and the loops are getting unmanageable. I would ideally like to use LINQ to search all fields at once and make it a simple if or statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ to Xml

```
string name = "Brian";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourXmlFile);
var matches = doc.Root
                 .Descendants("Option")
                 .Where(option => name.StartsWith(option.Element("NameStartsWith").Value))
                 .Select(option => option.Element("Data").Value);

foreach(var data in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Answer is: {data}");
}
```

[XContainer.Descendants Method (XName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) will return all elements with name passed as parameter from all hierarchical levels of current XElement.

If element `NameStartsWith` is optional inside `Option`, then just add checking for null in the chain of `LINQ` methods. `XElement.Element(XName name)` will return `null` if no such element exists.

```
var matches = doc.Root
                 .Descendants("Option")
                 .Where(option => option.Element("NameStartsWith") != null)
                 .Where(option => name.StartsWith(option.Element("NameStartsWith").Value))
                 .Select(option => option.Element("Data").Value);
```

If `Option` element contain more then one other elements which need to be selected, then create a class which represent all needed data and fill it inside `Select` method

```
public class Option
{
    public string NameStartsWith {get; set; }
    public string Data {get; set; }
    public string ElementOne {get; set; }
    public string ElementTwo {get; set; }
}

var matches = doc.Root
                 .Descendants("Option")
                 .Where(option => option.Element("NameStartsWith") != null)
                 .Where(option => name.StartsWith(option.Element("NameStartsWith").Value))
                 .Select(option => new Option
                 {
                     NameStartsWith = option.Element("Data").Value,
                     Data = option.Element("Data").Value,
                     ElementOne = option.Element("ElementOne").Value,
                     ElementTwo = option.Element("ElementTwo").Value,
                 });
```

Of course you can use anonymous class instead of created one.

Comment: Thanks for this, It works well aside from one issue. Sometimes there is not a `<NameStartsWith>` element inside every `<Option>`. I tried getting round this using: `.Where(option => name.StartsWith((string)option.Element("NameStartsWith") ?? ""))` , but in the foreach loop it returns a lot of empty results because I've just found out that all strings return true to `StartsWith.("")`.

I could use `.Where(option => hostname.StartsWith((string)option.Element("hostSW") ?? "omgwtfbbq"))` instead, but adding a random string in there just so it doesn't match seems a bit sloppy?

Comment: @JamesNapier This is the advantage of using xpath. It does all those checks for you....

Comment: @Fabio I'm finding the method you provided easier to understand than the xpath way. However, what I cannot seem to work out is how I can change the `.Select(...)` to select all of the elements under the matched `<option>` and not just a specific one like `<data>`.

Comment: Thanks again @Fabio. Is there any way to 'Select All' rather than individually specifying each element and then loop the results?

Comment: Now you are talking about serialization, where you can deserialize all values from xml to your classes. [XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

XPATH + Linq2Xml is also possible

```
string Name = "Brian";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //or XDocument.Load(filename)
var matches = xDoc
       .XPathSelectElements($"//Option/NameStartsWith[starts-with('{Name}', text())]");
```

Comment: Your path checks elements where value of element `NameStartsWith` starts with given name, but OP need elements where given name starts with value of element `NameStartsWith`

Comment: @Fabio No, it works as OP expects.... Even if it were wrong the only thing to change were the place of parameters of `starts-with`. `text(), '{Name}'`

Comment: @L.B Thanks for the reply. Can I ask if the $ sign is intentional in this bit of code `.XPathSelectElements($` - it doesn't want to compile when I have it present.

Comment: @JamesNapier  It is with VS2015. Equal to `"//Option/NameStartsWith[starts-with('" + Name + "', text())]"`

Comment: Ah OK thanks. Is it possible to use OR statements with xpath? For example if I wanted to add `|| "//Option/NameEndsWith[ends-with('{Name}', text())]"` for example?

Comment: @JamesNapier  Yes you use `or` :) See for ex, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx